# Codeigniter 3 Oracle Set Query Builder Case Insensitivity

Tags: php, sql, oracle, codeigniter

Using Codeigniter 3 at work with Oracle 12c and sporadic uses of the Query Builder class.

Query Builder is selecting from Oracle with escaped table names. I would like to configure the class to not do this. I'd like this call:

```
$query = $this->db->get('customers');
```

to go from

```
select * from 'customers';
```

to

```
select * from customers;
```

in generated SQL.

Is there a config item I don't know about or am I going to have to fix one of my coworker's queries every three weeks until the end of time?

Comment: Are you using the odbc database driver?

Comment: I'm using the Oci8 driver.

Comment: Use syntax `$this->db->select('SELECT * FROM customers', false)->get();`. Second parameter in `select` method if `false` will prevent CI escaping fields and table names. [Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data).

Comment: @Tpojka you should post that as an answer for future visitors.

Comment: I will if @khhaaannnnn tells it helped him.

Comment: That works @Tpojka. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use next syntax

```
$this->db->select('SELECT * FROM customers', false)->get();
```

since second parameter in `select($tablename, $escape=NULL)` method will prevent table name or field names escaping when set to `FALSE`.